# IllegalArgumentException in ProgressDialog.dismiss

Tags: android

I received this crash report:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:395)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:239)
at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:441)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:306)
at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:89)
at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:132)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:296)
at ZhuangDictActivity$1.onPageFinished(ZhuangDictActivity.java:311)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:299)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 311 in ZhuangDictActivity is searchProgressDialog.dismiss() below:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    searchProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    onConfigurationChanged(ZhuangDictActivity.this.getResources().getConfiguration());
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
```

This is the ProgressDialog.show:

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
                    searchProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
                    searchProgressDialog.show();
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                }
```

The crash occurred when the orientation is changed before the WebView finish loading.

Comment: where are you using the searchProgressDialog.show(); can u paste the code of that

Comment: Edited, please check.

Comment: when orientation changes the activity restarts, you have to make the changes in your manifest file under activity tag android:configChanges="orientation". This does not restarts the activity.

Comment: This question is a dupe, and the answers naive, so to help others who stumble upon this question, the best summary of solutions I've found so far is here: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are simply dismissing, not checking whether it is showing or not. You'll have to check it first:

```
if (searchProgressDialog != null && searchProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
    searchProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: I just found out that the crash occurred when the orientation is changed before the WebView finish loading. Is your code will work for this condition?

Comment: Yes..It will eork..here i am checking if window is showing then only dismissing..

Comment: you still get this exception when the activity is destroyed and you call dismiss (happens on async operations)

Answer (score 7):

Please override the onDestroy method.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    if((progressDialog != null) && progressDialog.isShowing() ){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its is because you are trying to show progress dialog ,but at that moment your activity seems to be destroy...

Comment: Yes, I just found out that the crash occurred when the orientation is changed before the WebView finish loading. So any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
       if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already dismissed the dialog through code, and you are doing it again. So please check whether dialog object is null or not before dismissing it.   And assign it to null.